# Remote Connection: Port must be between 0 and 65535 [NetBeans]

Tags: php, netbeans, ftp, vsftpd

I have been successfully connecting to online FTP server via Netbeans PHP IDE. But recently it stopped synchronising and saying

```
can't list files for "/"
```

I have been able to fix this by unchecking the passive Mode in filezilla, but in neatbeans when I uncheck passive mode, it give me error like

```
Remote Connection: Port must be between 0 and 65535.
```

Where as port 21 is already added. 
I am using netBeans current version 8.2. My FTP server is vsftp, running ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I already did solved this by downgrading to netbean 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workarounnd, still considered as a bug. Works for Me!

FTP

Port range is under passive mode, and when passive mode is not checked it should not make a difference if it's empty.

You need to scroll down to see the port range fields, UI is a bit awkward here. Enter 21 to 21. Try your connection.

Link to BUG: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262317